# Alignment of dropdown list and button in same line angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have tried many things on styling side and putting it into table nothing worked 
I want help in aligning the buttons and dropdown in the same new line

```
<div style="width:100%">
  <div style="width:40%" flex>
    <md-select ng-model="someModel">
      <md-option ng-value="NoModeSelected">No Mode Selected</md-option>
      <md-option ng-value="AllTwitter">All Twitter</md-option>
    </md-select>
  </div>
  <div style="width:20%" flex>
    <md-button ng-click="close()">+</md-button>
  </div>
  <div style="width:30%">
  <div>
    <md-input-container class="md-block language">
      <label translate>Dropdown For Filters</label>
      <md-select ng-model="accSettingsCtrl.userSettings.language" required>
        <md-option ng-repeat="lang in accSettingsCtrl.LANGUAGES" value="{{lang.key}}">
          {{lang.name}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

[Here is the image of what has been displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO3FT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same by using bootstrap. Here is the demo : http://codepen.io/shreya1289/pen/beweRy

If you don't want to use bootstrap, then you can apply `float:left` to the div's.

Comment: Thanks for your response